# Is it gerund? how can I know?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

I don't understand the function of "coming" word in the sentence below.

> As they weigh the scale of monetary easing coming later this month.

Is it working as a gerund? and if so, why is it in gerund?

Could I rewrite:

> As they weigh the scale of monetary easing which is coming later his
>   month.

Comment: This looks like a sentence fragment, like you cut off the first part for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "coming" is not a gerund in this particular sentence fragment though "easing" is.

Present participles can be confusing. They can be used as the substantive part of a verbal phrase as in

> I was washing the dishes.

The present participle "washing" in this explains what was going on.

A present participle can be used as an adjective to modify a noun.

> My washing machine broke.

The present participle "washing" in this case explains what kind of machine we are talking about.

A present participle can be used as a noun to identify a type of activity as in the following example.

> Washing a child's hair can be a fraught experience.

With respect to your example "coming this month" explains the timing of the easing and so is being used adjectivally to modify "easing."

Comment: Regarding your last example, "Washing a child's hair can be a fraught experience.": in that sentence "**washing**" (acting as a noun) is a gerund. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly. You have it. A gerund is a participle acting as a noun.